# error in ASP.NET Unrecognized database format 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\feedback.accdb'

Tags: asp.net

i made asp.net project on ms access. the db is successfully filled but why cant i retreive data from the database? it shows the upper mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic/answers/752312-unrecognized-database-format)

Use ADO's to connect to Access 2007

Or it maybe that your ASP.NET is too old, or the Access 2007 is too new for your ASP.NET version. [See this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t68765-unrecognized-database-format.html).